# Call an angular route from a custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, single-page-application

I have an AngularJS inside an ASP.NET MVC App. My use case is an accordion that is populated on click event. Each Item is a directive and in the template I have two divs one showing the header the second is hidden. Clicking the header I will populate with DOM the hidden div and open it, I tried with $http I got an issue, not resolving route with # but to my MVC controller

//This is my main Angular Module

```
    window.progCheckList = angular.module("progCheckList", []);

    progCheckList.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/MainCheckList", {
           controller: "mainCheckListCtrl",
           templateUrl: "/AngularJSApp/ProgramCheckList/Templates/mainCheckList.html"
        })
        .when("/MDFDecisions", {
           controller: "mdfDecisionsCtrl",
           templateUrl: "/AngularJSApp/ProgramCheckList/Templates/mdfDecisions.html"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/MainCheckList' });
       }
    ]);

//Inside of MainCheckList I have

    <div style="clear: both; display: block;">
         <check-list-item data-ng-repeat="checkList in data.ProgramCheckList.ProgramCheckLists" value="checkList">
        </check-list-item>
    </div>

//CheckListItem is a directive

progCheckList.directive('checkListItem', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "/AngularJSApp/ProgramCheckList/Templates/programCheckListItem.html",
        scope: { value: "=value" },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.find("button").on("click", function () {

            });

            element.find(".CheckListHeader").on("click", function () {
                if (scope.value.Action != null && scope.value.Action != "") {
                    if (element.find(".CheckListHeader").hasClass("collapsed")) {

                        $http({ method: 'GET', url: "Index#/MDFDecisions" }).
                            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                console.log(element.parent().find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next());

                                element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().html(data);

                                element.find(".CheckListHeader").removeClass("collapsed");
                                element.find(".CheckListHeader").addClass("expanded");

                                element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().show("slow");
                            }).
                            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                toastr("Unable to get action");
                            });

                        element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().show("slow");
                    } else if (element.find(".CheckListHeader").hasClass("expanded")) {
                        element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().empty();

                        element.find(".CheckListHeader").removeClass("expanded");
                        element.find(".CheckListHeader").addClass("collapsed");

                        element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().hide("slow");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

//The Template that I'm using for the Directive

<div class="program-checklist" style="clear: both; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0.4em; cursor: pointer;">
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; resize: vertical;">
        <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="CheckListHeader collapsed" style="float: left; vertical-align: middle; height: 3.5em;">
                <h4>{{value.Functionality}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 2em;">
                <button class="btn btn-inverse updateCheckList" data-ng-click="UpdateStatus(value.CPMSCheckListId)">
                    Update Status
                </button>

                <img data-ng-src="{{value.IsReady && '../../Images/Checked.png' || '../../Images/UnChecked.png'}}" style="width: 36px; height: 36px; margin: 0.5em;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both; display: none; width: 100%; height: 20em; overflow: auto;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

When I clicking the header I would expect to populate next DIV with the DOM calling the AngularJS route "Index#/MDFDecisions", I'm getting very weird result  it gets the Index MVC Action and not the AngularJS route.
 also 
Any idea how can I get my expected result? also I'm open to any improvement to my code. This is my second AngularJS App and I'm being using this approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came with a different solution. Instead of try to get DOM in the Directive I changed directive to have the hidden DIV with ng-include and change the src attribute in the Directive as scope value.

```
//Updated Directive Code
progCheckList.directive('checkListItem', function ($http) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/AngularJSApp/ProgramCheckList/Templates/programCheckListItem.html",
    scope: { value: "=value" },
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.find("button").on("click", function () {

        });

        element.find(".CheckListHeader").on("click", function () {
            if (scope.value.Action != null && scope.value.Action != "") {
                if (element.find(".CheckListHeader").hasClass("collapsed")) {

                    scope.checkListItemTemplate = "/AngularJSApp/ProgramCheckList/Templates/mdfDecisions.html";

                    scope.$apply();

                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").removeClass("collapsed");
                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").addClass("expanded");
                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().show("slow");
                } else if (element.find(".CheckListHeader").hasClass("expanded")) {
                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().empty();

                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").removeClass("expanded");
                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").addClass("collapsed");

                    element.find(".CheckListHeader").parent().next().hide("slow");
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
//Updated Directive Template
<div class="program-checklist" style="clear: both; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0.4em; cursor: pointer;">
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; resize: vertical;">
    <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="CheckListHeader collapsed" style="float: left; vertical-align: middle; height: 3.5em;">
            <h4>{{value.Functionality}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 2em;">
            <button class="btn btn-inverse updateCheckList" data-ng-click="UpdateStatus(value.CPMSCheckListId)">
                Update Status
            </button>

            <img data-ng-src="{{value.IsReady && '../../Images/Checked.png' || '../../Images/UnChecked.png'}}" style="width: 36px; height: 36px; margin: 0.5em;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; display: none; width: 100%; height: 30em; overflow: auto;" data-ng-include="" src="checkListItemTemplate">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are manipulating everything manually with jQuery instead of using Angular to make the changes to the DOM based on the model (`$scope`)?  See [this very popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) for more info.